# How can I perform a left join and exclude results that match a subquery in LINQ?

Tags: sql, linq

Need to convert this sql query to LINQ

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    parcels p
    LEFT JOIN leases l ON p.parcels_pk = l.parcels_fk
WHERE 
    l.parcels_fk IS NULL 
    AND p.parcels_pk NOT IN (SELECT parcels_fk FROM application_parcels)
ORDER BY parcel
```

tried this:

```
var qry = from p in db.Parcels
          join l in db.Leases on p.Id equals l.pk_parcel
          where l.pk_parcel == null 
                && !(from ap in db.ApplicationParcels 
                     select ap.ParcelId).Contains(p.Id)
                     orderby p.Name
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? The join? The subquery? Do you have a query that you started?

Comment: what have you tried, what isn't working for you? have you tried any of the tools available such as:  http://www.sqltolinq.com/ - a quick google search seems to yield plenty of options and resources for learning

Answer (score 3):

```cs
             // SELECT * FROM parcels
var result = from p in parcels
             // LEFT JOIN leases ON p.parcels_pk = l.parcels_fk
             join llj in leases on p.parcels_pk equals llj.parcels_fk into lj
             from l in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             // WHERE l.parcels_fk IS NULL
             where l.parcels_fk == null
             // AND p.parcels_pk NOT IN (...)
               && !application_parcels.Any(x => x.parcels_fk == p.parcels_pk)
             // ORDER BY [p.]parcel
             order by p.parcel
             select new { parcel = p, lease = l };
```

Assuming i have your schema correct.

But in the future:

- First supply what you've tried (show an effort).
- Have a look at LINQPad, it's very helpful.

Comment: Think you forgot the `into` on the left join